# Thumbnails for Image Files on Desktop won't load

Tags: finder, filesystem, desktop

I have a dozen or so image files on my iMac's desktop.  Most of the time, after booting up my computer, it displays a thumbnail of each image (as it should).  But sometimes, the thumbnails won't show up (see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot]

It appears to happen randomly.  I estimate that it happens about 20% of the time.

Why is this, and how can I prevent it from happening?  I am running OS X 10.9.4.  Thanks.

Comment: Open your [Console app](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/checkconsole.html). In the upper right corner, enter a search for `com.apple.IconServicesAgent`. Update your post, or supply a [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com) in your reply with the 10 most recent entries, if applicable.

Comment: @njboot Thanks, here are the search results I got back.  The problem occurred yesterday (8/26/14), but there don't seem to be any error messages for that day.  Also, the earliest log entry is only 3 days old, which seems strange.   http://pastebin.com/Wue07AH7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your log, I suggest trashing the Finder property list, then rebooting.

- Open Terminal
- Enter the following command `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`
- Restart
- If the issue persists, I suggest [following these instructions.](https://gist.github.com/walesmd/7315613) to completely reset the service.

Further information: [The X Lab's Maverick's Post Installation Issues](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/mavericks_post_install.html#IconServicesAgent)

Comment: Thanks.  I've run the `rm` command.  If the problem does not surface in a week or so, then I will consider it fixed. :)

Comment: Nope.  It happened again. :( The `rm` command didn't work.  I tried the longer set of instructions.  We'll see if that works.

Comment: So, it seems to be working now.  Marking as answered.  Thanks again! :)

Comment: What other settings will this erase?

Answer (score 2):

OMG [that linked gist](https://gist.github.com/walesmd/7315613) did solve it! (from Apple forums).

Here is the bit that worked and fixed it:

- `mkdir ~/tmp-quicklook`
- `mv /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.quicklook.* ~/tmp-quicklook/`
- Log out/Log in (or reboot)
- `sudo mv ~/tmp-quicklook/com.apple.quicklook.* /System/Library/LaunchAgents`
- Log out/log in (or reboot)

(the two "resets" are really necessary)

Still the folder preview doesn't work but looks like it's much harder to fix:

[image: desktop]

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same issue by going (in the Finder) to View->Show View Options. There, I moved the Icon Size slider to a larger size. All the image thumbnails loaded. Then I returned the slider to my selected size.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click: show view options
2. Show icon preview: yes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to some of my image files as thumbnails on the Desktop. I simply went to Force Quit and relaunched Finder. Images all returned to these thumbnails. Hope this helps s.o.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It's helpful if you explain how to "Force Quit" an application for the visitors who are not familiar with that procedure.