# No previews for Desktop files on Mojave

Tags: finder, mojave, preview, desktop

Here is what it looks like (two regular png images which previews were working fine before I upgraded to Mojave). Third one is a folder with custom picture and it was like that on High Sierra too. About the filenames, I like using spaces but using anything else don't change anything.

[image: files]

Here is what I've tried:

- Right click on Desktop, then "View options" -> "Show icon preview" (disabling/enabling it doesn't change anything)
- Restart computer
- Restart Finder
- I don't see anything in `system.log`
- I couldn't find much in "Console" in general
- I also tried to mess with the IconServiceAgent ([stack overflow answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143278/thumbnails-for-image-files-on-desktop-wont-load), [linked gist with details](https://gist.github.com/walesmd/7315613))

Thanks for the duplicate suggestion, I found this is Console when starting iconserviceagent manually (either root or not):

```
iconservicesagent[20837]: assertion failed: 18A391: libxpc.dylib + 39253
```

```
Finder[870]: objc[870]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder (0x10a018b80) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (0x10e74ddc8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, I remember removing the plist but didn't try to linked gist: https://gist.github.com/walesmd/7315613

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers to this! I might have got script this if we can use it at work.